# create foreign key using another database table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have sqlite database which contain one table with column id.
I want to create anther table in different database with foreign key of existing table column id in python sqlite3

Comment: Did you read https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html ?

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a foreign key constraint referencing a table in a different database.